# Area of Overlapping Quadrilateral Tiles

Tags: geometry

I was studying for some quizzes when I stumbled across this question. It goes like this:

> Two regular quadrilaterals vinyl tiles each of $1$ foot long on each sides overlap each other such that the overlapping region is a regular octagon. What is the area of the overlapping region?

My work:

I imagined the problem like this:
[image]

The area of the shaded blue region is what I want to get. I don't know if one side of the octagon is one-third of that of the side of square, because my calculated area is slightly larger than that of my book's answer.

How do you get the area of the blue region above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ be a length-side of the octagon $ABCDE...$, where $BC$ placed on the square side.

Thus, since $\sin45^{\circ}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, we obtain:$$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a}{2}=a\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt2},$$
which gives $a=\sqrt2-1$.

Thus, $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a}{2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt2-1}{2}=\frac{2-\sqrt2}{2}$ and the needed area is
$$1-4\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2-\sqrt2}{2}\right)^2=1-\frac{1}{2}(2-\sqrt2)^2=2\sqrt2-2$$

Comment: How did you derived the expression above? What is the thought process?

Comment: @Palautot Ka Say me please, are my answer and the answer in your book, same?

Comment: The area of a regular polygon is $A = \frac{a^2 n }{4} \cot \frac{180^o}{a}.$ Using your $a = \sqrt{2} -1$ and $n = 8$ sides, I got the area to be 0.8284 square feet. Is your value $4 \sqrt{2} - 5$ the area of the blue octagon?

Comment: @Palautot Ka I fixed my post. See now please.

Comment: The book's answer is 119.29 square inchesXD

Comment: @Palautot Ka I think your book mistakes. We can not get a value greater than $1$. Maybe there is some relation between foot and inch?

Comment: It's fine....you're value of $a = \sqrt{2} -1$ is correct. When I get the area, I got 0.8284 square feet. When converting it to square inches, it becomes 119.29 square inches. It's fine....heheh

Comment: @Palautot Ka If so, we are done! What do you think?

Comment: Gee........Thanks for the help man!

Comment: @Palautot Ka You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The area of the shaded region will be an octagon - one square minus 4 white triangles. Say the legs of the right triangles are *l*. Then 
$$2l+{\sqrt{2l^2}} = 1$$
from the Pythagorean theorem. Solving for *l* we get $$1-{\sqrt2}/2$$
The area will then be 
$$1-4*l^2/2$$
giving us 
$$2*{\sqrt2}-2$$

Comment: I like the insight......

Answer (score 0):

The height of a triangle is the half of the diagonal of a square minus the side of a square.

The area of a triangle (isoceles rectangle) is the square of the height.

Hence the blue area

$$1^2-4\frac{\left(\sqrt2-1\right)^2}4=2\sqrt2-2.$$

[image]